# Benefits of SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

I use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in the majority of my general SQL queries, mainly because this was drilled in to me when originally learning the language.

From my understanding, this isolation level acts the same way that `WITH (NO LOCK)` however I only ever tend to use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.

- Is there ever a time that I should be using `WITH (NO LOCK)` over `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`.
- Does  `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` stop other users from being locked out of the tables that I am reading?
- If  `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` is used to stop locks, but I am only reading data, what is the point in using it? Is it only system intensive queries that would generate locks? Is it worth using it when running queries that would return in say, 5-10 seconds?
- I have been told not to use  `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` when reading data that would be used in updates, presumably to avoid updating dirty data. Would this be the only reason?
- With the type of database that I am working on, there is a production and testing environment. We will very rarely be querying the production environment but when I need to, I will generally be using `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` in my query. I understand that dirty reads are possible with this. Aside from receiving data back that may not end up being committed to the database (and therefore throw my results out) what other types of 'dirty reads' could be possible?

Sorry for the mass questions.

Comment: You could read the same data twice is another pit fall. Using RU or NO LOCK as standard is a bad idea.

Comment: I wouldn't use `READ UNCOMMITTED` everywhere, in the exact same way as I wouldn't use `WITH (NOLOCK)` everywhere (they are essentially the same thing) http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Look into the SNAPSHOT isolation models. They are very much stronger than RCU and also do not block or cause blocking. They sound like a good default model for you (instead of defaulting to RCU!).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is terrible, that you learned it that way (sorry!).

`READ UNCOMMITTED` let's you read every row, yes. Even those who are currently used in an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` operation. This is very useful if you need to take a quick look at some Data or in mission critical `SELECT`-Statements where a block would be very harmful.

In fact, you risk your integrity. It may occur that you read a row, which is currently used to be deleted or in a change. It can also appear that you read a wrong value. This may be really uncommon, but it can happen. What do I mean with that? Well, think of a row which is very broad (it has many columns with many long `nvarchar`-columns). An update occur on this row and sets new values. In rare cases it can happen to you, that you read only a half row. Another thing can happen for example, if a user changes his login values. He changes his mail + password. The mail is already set, but the password isn't. This way you have a inconsistent state.

I would suggest to forget about `READ UNCOMMITTED`. Just use it where it's **really** needed.

Another alternative for you can be to enable the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option - therefor you can use `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` due to the enabled row versioning in your tempdb. This way you just read another (older) version of a row. This won't block your Queries. But it may occur that you read an old value too, but an consistent old value.

Another idea can be `WITH(READPAST)` instead of `WITH(NOLOCK)`. You will read the old state of the table (a bit like in the `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`), but you'll skip all currently locked rows instead.

Comment: @Ionic, thank you very much for the response! I really appreciate the help on that.

Comment: @HingeSight, it sounds like it, but there is a very good chance that it was my interpretation of the statement, thanks either way for your input.

Comment: `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` does not need to be enabled in order to turn on `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT`.  Only the `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` database option needs to be enabled so that row versioning instead of locking for read consistency, avoiding the need for dirty reads.

Comment: Yes I meaned that @DanGuzman. Sorry the answer was a bit unclear in that point. I edited it. :-)

Comment: With READPAST you will skip records that are locked, you won't get the old values -- so the only place I have figured out it could be used is queue handling

Comment: I clarified the sentence for you @JamesZ. I never said it would read the old values. Only the old state, which was intended that just the rows which are not currently locked will be returned. I added a side-sentence to clarify it.

Comment: This paradigm is so common in programming. "Hey, this safety feature/pattern/convention that experts put in place to keep me from ruining my data sure is inconvenient. I'll just disable it for a little bit since *I know what I'm doing*."

Comment: Well I wouldn't see it that drastically. Yes it's not a good practice at all. But I've seen some environments where you need to handle like this. A friend of mine has a mainframe which gets all data pushed into different tables from many production machines. All of them were permanently pushing data (due to their design) to inform robots and so on. He barely cannot read some tables, as those machines just update some counters. If he wants to display the currently pushthrough he needs to read it dirty and maybe a bit inaccurate, but otherwise he won't be able to read it properly. :-)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine practice as long as the data you are reading is NOT mission critical. For example, I have a photo website hosted for a client of mine which processes thousands of agency photos each hour. In my searching procedures, I use nolock to prevent delays in displaying the results to the user who is performing searches.

Answer (score 3):

In most databases, the vast majority of activity, even inserts, deletes and updates, are outside of explicit transactions.

Sure, `READ UNCOMMITTED` (Dirty Reads) can provide incorrect information in these cases, but that information WAS correct 5 seconds earlier.

The times when Dirty Reads produce genuinely bad results are when a Transaction fails and has to be rolled back or when running a query against two tables that are normally updated together using an explicit transaction.

Meanwhile, on a typical large, busy database that has a 100 (or more) to 1 ratio of reads to writes, EVERY single (read) query that doesn't use Dirty Reads is slowing the system down because it needs to obtain and check for locks AND it is making it much more likely that transactions will fail (typically due to Deadlocks) which can cause more serious database integrity issues.

Instead, using dirty reads makes the system MUCH faster and more reliable (in part because of the improved performance making inconsistencies less likely to happen).

Sure, there are times when they shouldn't be used. I dislike setting the database to default to using the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level or even using the explicit `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` statement at the start of SQL Scripts and SPs - there is too much chance that a Dirty Read will happen when it shouldn't. Instead, the `(NOLOCK)` hints are a much better approach since they explicitly indicate that the programmer thought about what they were doing and decided that, for this specific table in this specific query, Dirty Reads were safe.

If you are programming an application to transfer money from one bank account to another, you should not be using Dirty Reads. But most applications do not need that level of paranoia.

Answer (score 2):

As the accepted answer states, forget about using READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level (except when really needed) as you risk reading wrong data. But to answer the 3rd bullet point in your question there are two situations I find useful:

1. When writing and testing SQL Server SSIS packages, the steps of the package may be wrapped in a transaction. If you are testing a package by running it step by step in the SSIS debugger, you may want to examine tables while there are locks on the table. Using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED allows you to use SQL Server Manager Studio to examine the tables while the package is being debugged.
2. In SQL Server Manager Studio you may want to test T-SQL code by wrapping it in a transaction to give you the option of rolling back the changes. For example on a test database you may want to restore data to the initial state as part of your test. If you are testing transaction-wrapped code and you want to check locked tables while the transaction is underway, you can use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED to examine the values in another window.

I accept these are fairly obscure uses for READ UNCOMMITTED, but I have found them useful in a test environment.